# Hiding the content of a <div> and showing another <div> with different contents

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div with contents of pics

```
             <div class="1">
               <div class="2">
                 <img src="img/aa.png"></img>

               </div>
               <div class="3">         
                 <img src="img/bb.png"></img>

               </div>
              <div class="4">         
               <img src="img/cc.png"></img>

               </div>
              </div>
```

and I want to replace it with another div with different contents

```
          <div class="w">
             <div class="x">
                <h3>name</h3>
            <ul>
                   <li>bday</li>
                     <li>age</li>
            </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
```

how can i interchange this divs by just clicking a text or hypertext and without refreshing or reloading the page. this is the text to be clicked

```
                     <div class="1a">
                        <a class="s" href="prof.htm">PROFILE</a>
                  </div>
```

what could be the code should I use to hide/show the divs 
(I am knowledgable in HTML,CSS,JQUERY)

please help me.... sorry i am very new and interested in the field

Comment: Tried any code so far? If you have not tried anything, you should try it before asking here. Once you have tried something, disclose what you have tried. You may show the code and issues/error messages that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".s").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(".1").is(":visible"))  {
        $(".w").show();
        $(".1").hide();
    } else {
        $(".1").show();
        $(".w").hide();
    }
});
```

Using jQuery, just test if the first element you want is visible (I assumed 1 just on order you posted), and hide()/show() respectively

However, when you click that link, you will be redirected!

So, add preventDefault so that it does not perform it's normal duty of changing the page

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper div with a class and define id to the link as I did and use Jquery's .toggle() if you want to toggle or use .hide() and .show() if you just want to hide and show once.

Here is the working example - http://jsfiddle.net/X59tp/2/

Here is the code

```
 $( "#clicker" ).click(function() {
  $( ".toggler" ).toggle( "fast" );
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can add Jquery to your HTML file either by downloading the code and linking it to your html OR by CDN. Please go to jquery.com or just google if you want to learn.

Comment: Please check the example I have just updated with what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Check below link..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X59tp/2/)

```
<script type="javascript">
    $(".s").on("click",function() {
       if ($(".1").is(":visible"))  {
           $(".w").show();
           $(".1").hide();
       } else {
           $(".1").show();
           $(".w").hide();
       }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: how can I connect the javascript file and the html file?

Comment: You can use Jquery library in your head section of HTML page. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> and copy and paste previous code in the down of jquery library.